# Even + Odd Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

How can we express $f(x) = \ln x, x>0$ as a sum of even and odd function?

We know that every function can be written as a sum of even and odd function. What about this one here? Somebody help.

Comment: How do you define even and odd for a function not defined on $\mathbb{R}$, but only on $\mathbb{R}_+^\ast$?

Comment: $\ln(x)$ is not defined in the negatives !

Comment: Not every function. It is every function defined on $\mathbb{R}$!

Comment: I missed this point. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, *we know that **not** every function can be written as a sum of even and odd function.* For example functions defined on natural numbers (i.e. sequences) have only positive arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\ln x$ is ony defined for $x>0$, you can simply use the even and the odd extension to $\mathbb R$:
\begin{align}
f_e(x) &= \begin{cases}
\tfrac12 ln |x| & x\ne 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}\\
f_o(x) &= \begin{cases}
f_e(x) & x\ge 0\\
-f_e(x) & x<0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Obviously $f_e$ is even and $f_o$ is odd. And for $x>0$, $f_e(x)+f_o(x) = \ln x$.

Comment: Simpler: $f_e(x) = \ln|x|$ and $f_o(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. However their sum is not the original function, because its domain differs from $\mathbb R^+$, on which $\ln$ is defined.

Answer (score 3):

$\ln(|x|)$ is an even function.

Comment: He is asking $\ln x$ not $\ln (\lvert x \rvert)$

Comment: (With domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$: this is implicit, but just in case.)

Comment: @ShahidMShah: I know, read my comment in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Even function's domain is symmetric with respect to zero (that is for each $x$ in domain, $-x$ belongs to the domain, too). Same for odd functions. Consequently the domain of a sum of an even and an odd function will be symmetric wrt. zero. And the logarithm's domain is not symmetric, so it **can't** be expressed as a sum of even and odd function.